# SpecFlow \ Solution Explorer file icons

Tags: visual-studio-2010, specflow, solution-explorer

I can't get the icons to show up for SpecFlow files in the Solution Explorer. Everything else works fine. Any ideas?

This is for Visual Studio 2010.

Does anyone know how to edit the icons associated to a file extension in Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Install Specflow's visual studio plugin http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9915524d-7fb0-43c3-bb3c-a8a14fbd40ee. You need this as well as the NuGet assembly if you are editing your features.

Comment: Tried that already. It says that it is already installed in all available products. I also tried removing the extension and reinstalling... but no joy.